# Where is the 'Flight' Gate Seal located?

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

I know it is in Oreba 300 AF but I cannot seem to find it. I have wandered around for a while now with no luck. I am guessing it is obvious and right in front of me... but alas I cannot find it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The answer that was here was deleted by my request in relation [to this discussion](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/3971/3389) on the meta-discussion site.

Comment: simply googling it will yield in a table, in my cause the first option would be, but i'm not sure whetether or not i can post it here seeing the above comment.

Comment: I'm sure its 300 AF and not 305 AF cause as far as i am aware there is no oerba 305 AF at least not in the historia crux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Flight" Gate Seal is located in Oerba 300 AF. It is in a treasure box atop the stairs just south-west of the deserted schoolhouse. After the first flight of stairs check the balcony above the bush and use Moogle Thrown to catch the box.

[image: Throw Moogle up there!]

Not to be confused with the "How Things Were" Gate Seal, placed in Oerba 300 AF as well.

Comment: -1 This answer doesn't add anything extra that hasn't already been answered.

Comment: The first answer is wrong. That's not the Flight Gate Seal, but the "How Things Were" Gate Seal.

Comment: You need to mention that in your answer.  Re-answering the question briefly like this, looks more like a "Me-too!" sort of thing than contributing anything meaningful.

Comment: I add a note. I think it would be more correct commenting the other answer than pointing out it's wrong in my own answer, but I don't have enough reputation yet.

Answer (score 4):

The treasurebox is behind some boxes south-east of the deserted schoolhouse.
you should use moogle throw to get it

[image: Location of the Flight Gate Seal]

[image: Location of the Flight Gate Seal]

Comment: As mentioned in @Sep answer, the screenshots are showing the "Way things were" Seal. (PS3)

Comment: Hmm ill check once i get back home. but weird that my answer got flagged as correct then